# Cannot find external partitions from Live USB

Tags: partition, dual-boot, system-installation, data-recovery

I have a dual-booted laptop (Windows 10 and Manjaro).
After changing the battery (which was not functioning properly anymore), I could not log into Manjaro anymore and I am trying to first recover all the files in my Home folder, before making a clean re-install.

I have created a separate partition for the Home directory, which is then mounted on Manjaro. By logging into Windows and checking for the partitions on the disk, I obtain the following:

[image]

I am not sure as to why it indicates for most partitions to be "100%" free, but I am assuming it is because it does not recognize the Linux formatting and therefore assumes it is junk data? In any case, I believe that it is partition 7 that has my home directory.

In order to access it, I then tried to run Manjaro (version 249-7-2, the same version I had installed Manjaro on the laptop before) on a live usb (64G). However, when I check for partitions naively using the terminal, it only seems to show me the partitions of the live usb itself (as the total space is about 64G) instead of the laptop.

[image]
[image]

In fact, just trying to install from the live usb gives me an error stating that it cannot detect any devices to install it on?

[image]

Comment: Please try something fresh, e.g. Fedora 38

Comment: Yes. Do as @ArtemS.Tashkinov says. Get a live distro that isn't several years old.   —You could also try Ubuntu, Fedora, or other flavors while you attempt to access those partitions.  
 —Use one that comes with support for the file systems you use.